# how to create a texture with random circles on an irregular shape

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I tried to do it exploiting the Voronoi texture, but the result shows elongated circles on the surface of the body. How can I change the node tree?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer might be simpler than you think. I think part of your problem is that you switched the nodes to 2D - this is generally for things without depth or that have a texture that is mapped to a UV map. Have a try with this setup (note that I set the randomness of the Voronai to 0 - this is to make the most "perfect" circles possible, but it also takes a bit of randomness away from the distribution - balance as needed):

[image: VoronaiSimple]

Increase the scale of the Voronai for more dots:

[image: VoronaiSimple2]

If you're looking for more diversity of shape (randomness to the edges), you can warp your input vector using a Vector Math node and some other texture (I used a Noise Texture). As you can see, I used a MixRgb node to mix the values from the noise texture with almost pure white, otherwise the "Warp" effect is far too strong, and leaves undesired results.

[image: Warped]

Comment: Thank you!! Can you also tell me how to make them more irregular? Maybe some of them more elongated or with irregularities on the boundaries?

Comment: I thought elongated shapes were something you were trying to avoid.... Regardless, I updated my answer with (one) possible solution.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve